# How to create an array with dimension based on a variable?

Tags: python, numpy

I've got two variables: `dim` and `terms`. I'd like to use these variables to define an array. For example,

- If `dim=2` and `terms=4`, I'd like `m=np.zeros((4,4))`
- If `dim=3` and `terms=4`, I'd like `m=np.zeros((4,4,4))`
- If `dim=3` and `terms=3`, I'd like `m=np.zeros((3,3,3))`

I tried defining the argument using a string but it doesn't accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
np.zeros((terms,) * dim)
```